# Android element visibility not working properly

Tags: java, android, video, visibility

Hi I got problem with setting up a visibility. My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget324"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/onbg"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<Button android:id="@+id/topBtn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</Button>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/introvid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 </VideoView>   
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Kn8s"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/kn8s"
    android:layout_width="430.50dp"
    android:layout_height="121.00dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10.00dp"
    /> 
<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/introimage"
    android:src="@drawable/pcintro"
    android:layout_width="215.25dp"
    android:layout_height="197.00dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

and my .java file is:

```
import (...)

public class Intro extends Activity {
    VideoView vid;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);
        vid = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.introvid);
        String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.onbg;
vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
        vid.start();
        FrameLayout widget324 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.widget324);
        widget324.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Intent OnIntent = new Intent(Intro.this, On.class);
                        startActivity(OnIntent);
                        Intro.this.finish();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 }
                return true;
            }});    

        final MediaPlayer mpGo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro);
        mpGo.start();          

        final ImageView productions = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Kn8s);
        productions.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    productions.findViewById(R.id.Kn8s).setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 10500);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    Intent OnIntent = new Intent(Intro.this, On.class);
                    startActivity(OnIntent);
                    Intro.this.finish();
            }
    }, 12000);     
        }   }
```

Problem is that an element called here "(R.id.Kn8s)" should apear after 10,5 sec (10500) but it doesn't. I noticed that when time is set under 1 sec (999) it works fine! Also noticed that when I throw away video view the "Kn8s" element becomes visible after time that it should be! Why it doesn't work? It should be declared onStart method? or I don't know... is that about the software acceleration? Thx for every answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
 productions.findViewById(R.id.Kn8s).setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

with

`productions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

You've already initialized productions before the delay, so you don't have to initialize again after the delay.

Don't know how I missed it but, this seems to be the problem:

```
 productions.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                productions.findViewById(R.id.Kn8s).setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 10500);
```

Replace the above code with

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                productions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 10500);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have tried that but did not solve the problem, however it is good to know that I can code in that way :) and code looks nicer now!

Answer (score 0):

hey thanks to Janmejoy's answer I have found solution for my problem! all I had to do is to change this part of my xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Kn8s"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/kn8s"
    android:layout_width="430.50dp"
    android:layout_height="121.00dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10.00dp"
    />
```

in to:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Kn8s"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:src="@drawable/kn8s"
    android:layout_width="430.50dp"
    android:layout_height="121.00dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10.00dp"
    />
```

Well can someone tell me why "gone" works while "invisible" don't!?
acording to :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348547/1873367
"
View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. 
View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
"
So if that is it, in my case it shouldn't matter! or should?