# android add more button like that in the contacts application

Tags: android, android-layout

Am working with an application that contains a form filling with a contact information, and the contact may has many phone numbers, I added many edit texts to enter those phones and a button near the first one which show the next edit text when the user press on it

**The problem is I don't know what to write inside the on click listener of that button, I only want to show and hide the edit texts such that in the contacts application**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Invisible and Gone at Visiblity. The Gone it will hide AND remove his place. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348150/android-why-setvisibilityview-gone-or-setvisibilityview-invisible-do-not)