# How to handle this type of events

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview

### I want to make a button like this. In which you can add more forms.

---

[image]

---

### These type of form will generate.

---

[image]

how to create and handle this type of event in android. This image is taken from ios but i want to implement it in android.

Thanks in advance. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: inflate layout of your raw.xml via programmatically and use addView(View) method for add your hidden view..

Comment: Add a button of your choice and set an Edittext visibility GONE or VISIBLE on click.

Comment: can you give me any link of that tutorial?

Comment: I want to add infinite number of editText in the same scenario.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854165/android-add-more-button-like-that-in-the-contacts-application

Comment: refer this link exact solution what u want : http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html

Comment: @Febi M Felix In my case i want to add one form which has 3 edittexts.

Comment: @Dixit Patel You give me nice idea but i need edittext. actully i am not that professional in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps:

```
1) take hidden Layout. 
2) Make one layout that include your Button ,    Editext.. etc. 
3) When Click on Plus Button inflate layout & add it to hidden layout.
```

use this code :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);

// Access button & Edittext like:
Button mButton= (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.mButton);
EditText mEdiText= (EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.mEditText);

LinearLayout hiddenLinear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
hiddenLinear.addView(mView);
```

**EDIT**

for adding multiple EditText use **FOR** Loop

```
  LinearLayout hiddenLinear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

        for (int i = 0, l <= 3; i++) 
       {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);

        // Access button & Edittext like:
        Button mButton= (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.mButton);
        EditText mEdiText= (EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.mEditText);
         hiddenLinear.addView(mView);
        }
```

& for getting all EditText Value from All View use this Method:

```
LinearLayout hiddenLinear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
findAllEdittexts(hiddenLinear);


 ArrayList<EditText> array = new ArrayList<>();

    private void findAllEdittexts(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
                findAllEdittexts((ViewGroup) view);
            else if (view instanceof EditText) {
                EditText edittext = (EditText) view;
                array.add(edittext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice idea Dixit now if I will add that form 3 time and I have data in all that 3 edittext so how can I get that data?