# How to display a spinner when a radio button clicked

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, visibility, android-radiobutton

I want to display a spinner on the screen only if a radio button is clicked but I couldn't find a solution. Here is my current code.

```
    RadioGroup radio_grp=(RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio_grp);
    RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);



    View.OnClickListener button1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Toast message etc.
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener button2Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I want to show a spinner if they click the second radio button

        }
    };

    rb1.setOnClickListener(button1Listener);
    rb2.setOnClickListener(button2Listener);

    return rootView;
```

Comment: design your layout file with spinner with property visibility='gone' or 'invisible' and when you click the radio button make it visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First initialize the spinner like:

```
Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mSpinner);
```

Of course, before that, add a spinner in your layout somewhere, and set it's `android:visibility="invisible"` if the first selected radio button is 1, else set it to `visible`. Then add listeners:

```
View.OnClickListener button2Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // I want to show a spinner if they click the second radio button
        if (v.getId() == R.id.radioButton1) mSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.radioButton2) mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
};
```

If you don't want it to occupy any space once it's not on the screen, use `View.GONE`instead of `View.INVISIBLE`. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348150/android-why-setvisibilityview-gone-or-setvisibilityview-invisible-do-not) for the difference.

Comment: This seems like a good implementation. Might want to reference View.GONE and how View.INVISIBLE may be better for the OP, or let them decide.

Answer (score -1):

Put  `((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner)).performClick();` in second radiobutton click

```
View.OnClickListener button2Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

    ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner)).performClick();
            }
        };
```

Comment: please read the question first before answer this is visibility issue please check it