# visibility gone not working

Tags: android

I have a cascate menu with inner elements. You can navigate on 2nd level and you should be able to return back to main one. The problem is that, notwithstanding the button animation hide the back button, it remains active on the background. 
View.Gone is not working. Note: i use linear layouts.

```
/** CLICK SUL PULSANTE INDIETRO DA DASHBOARD */
dash_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exitRight(dd);
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         navigateRight(ll);
                         section = "main";
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                },
                200);
     }
 });
```

Comment: may be this will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348150/android-why-setvisibilityview-gone-or-setvisibilityview-invisible-do-not/15200170

Comment: increase Time . set `2000`

Comment: still not working incrasing the time

Comment: What did you want to achieve with `new android.os.Handler().postDelayed`?

Comment: let animation end

Comment: Okay, but by using `new android.os.Handler()` you can't tell the layout because it is inside a  UI thread. You haven't specific the thread ye. So, try using `Looper.getMainLooper()` for your Handler. Something like this `new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`